# Python: simply print datetime.now() including correct timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, date-formatting

How can I print current date/time formatted in a way which include correct timezone indication? I read [`datetime` format mini-language here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and so I've simply tried:

```
>>> '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z}'.format(datetime.now())
'2014-10-04 20:33:07 '
```

But as you can see timezone is not printed. My locale is `it-IT`, hours/minutes is correct, so I expected `%z` to print `+0200`.

Comment: Try `datetime.utcnow()`.  `datetime.now()` is not time-zone aware.

Comment: @SethMMorton `datetime.utcnow()` gives time in UTC (so 2 hours back) and anyway does not print timezone.

Comment: @SethMMorton: `utcnow()` is also naive datetime object (utcnow() - time in UTC, now() - local time)

Comment: related: [Getting computer's utc offset in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3168096/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `datetime.astimezone(tz)` [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111317/how-do-i-print-a-python-datetime-in-the-local-timezone) below;-

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

utc_dt = datetime(2009, 7, 10, 18, 44, 59, 193982, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print(utc_dt.astimezone(get_localzone())) # print local time
# -> 2009-07-10 14:44:59.193982-04:00
```

Comment: Ok, so... In Python this is possible only with additional modules?!?

Comment: to get the current time in the local timezone: `datetime.now(get_localzone())`

Comment: Yes lorenzo as sebastian mentioned

Comment: @lorenzo-s: [follow the related link that I've provided in the comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3168096/4279), to find stdlib only solution (for the current time).

Comment: @lorenzo-s: to support arbitrary dates (not only now), you need the tz database such as provided by `pytz` module. There is [PEP-0431 that suggests adding the zoneinfo to stdlib](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0431/).