# Python get local timezone offset in hours

Tags: python

I need to get the local timezone offset in hours.

eg: 0530 is my UTC offset. How can I print this in python

```
>>>print (datetime.datetime.now()) 
>>>2017-04-20 10:33:49.272839
```

This is in my local time zone. Which is +0530 UTC. So I need to print (or get) +0530

Comment: Do you mean actually just printing out "0530" in the proper format, or computing your timezone?

Comment: can you give an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: Also this might have more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111317/how-do-i-print-a-python-datetime-in-the-local-timezone

Comment: I edited my question